# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>)

Tags: java, android

```
 UnknownException: (Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{*.*.lordshivahdwallpapers/.*.lordshivahdwallpapers.activity.ImageLodingValues}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:472)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at *.*.lordshivahdwallpapers.activity.ImageLodingValues.onCreate(ImageLodingValues.java:58)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
java.lang.RuntimeException: (Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gauravkhannamarketeer.lordshivahdwallpapers/com.gauravkhannamarketeer.lordshivahdwallpapers.activity.ImageLodingValues}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

> XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mahadev_imagesbg"
    tools:context="*.*.activity.ImageLodingValues" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/header"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_thin"
        android:text="Mahadev Images"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout3">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/masonry_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>



<include
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    layout="@layout/google_ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/text_layer"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/include2"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="25dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Pull Down To Refresh"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> GOOGLE AD XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad"
    ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Build.Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*****"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation group: 'com.google.http-client', name: 'google-http-client', version: '1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:11.1.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:3.8.4'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
}
```

why this Error Comes Any one Have Idea

UnknownException: (Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gauravkhannamarketeer.lordshivahdwallpapers/com.gauravkhannamarketeer.lordshivahdwallpapers.activity.ImageLodingValues}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class )

Error was Reported by the CrashReports
Error Comes In

> Divece OS: 4.4.4
>   Device Model: Hongmi 2(Redmi 2)
>   Divice Sub Model: 2014818

Thanks In Advance

Comment: This is your full xml layout?

Comment: yes @MeosCoder in tools:context hide package name for privacy reason

Comment: Need add close `ContraintLayout` tag at end of xml </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: Post your included google_ad.xml file too

Comment: added please check @Abilash

Comment: attach your `build.gradle` file

Comment: @TejasPandya Atteched Please Check

Comment: please upvote the que... downvotted que makes wrong impression on user @TejasPandya

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki i understand but i havent downvoted your que bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of All from your error log

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
>   inflating class )

it seems like You have some kind of problem with ConstraintLayout. but you have properly included library ,as well as properly mentioned Constraint layout in xml .

So There might be one issuie with this code .

```
 android:background="@drawable/mahadev_imagesbg"
```

At runtime, Android resize's images based on need (based on the screen size and resolution). It uses Bitmap for doing the resizing internally. Which is very memory intensive . So Your device  **Hongmi 2(Redmi 2)** having memory problem and it is generating error.

So try one solution : copy this(mahadev_imagesbg) image to  drawable-ldpi, mdpi, hdpi folders and test it again with that device . or else try with lower resolution image .
 May be it will solve your issue.

Comment: thanks for the answer i dont now bcz this image is alredy compressed but again i will try this solution